# Why does the "Disable workflow" button not appear to me?

Tags: github-actions

According to [Disabling and enabling a workflow - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/disabling-and-enabling-a-workflow), clicking the `...` button will display a dropdown menu showing `Disable workflow` in there:

[image]

However it doesn't in [my case](https://github.com/QuaCau-TheSphere/quan-ly-du-an-va-cong-cu-nghi/actions/workflows/pages/pages-build-deployment):

[image]

Do you know why is that? [Here is the repo](https://github.com/QuaCau-TheSphere/CV-obsidian-quan-ly-du-an-va-cong-cu-nghi). If you look at it you will see that there is no `.github` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your repo enter `Settings` tab. Then on the left you can see `Actions` drop down. Open `General`. Here you can disable actions.

Comment: where can I find all actions apply to my repo?

Comment: @Ooker In `Actions` tab on the left pane all workflows are listed. But you need to enable actions first. When actions are disabled, actions tab is gone.

Comment: I mean, in that tab how can I identify the source of the workflows? I have no `.github` folder to begin with. Also, even if I add it elsewhere, why doesn't the "Disable workflow" button appear to me?

Comment: @Ooker For the repo you mentioned in the question, `Github Pages` is active. github pages do not need a workflow file to work. You can find it's setting in `Settings` tab and on the left tab press `Pages`